# Change background using dropdown box [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple program that changes the background image using a drop down box. Once the user makes the choice and the background saves, it saves a cookie that is remembered and used when the user joins the site again. It should show their last chosen background choice. This is what I've got so far but I'm really struggling with the cookie part. Could you help?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/vitalwheat/pen/LYVgVab)

````
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <title>Cookies!</title>
    <link href="cookies.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body onLoad="setCookie(this.value)">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>User Preferences</h1>
      <div class="test">
        skin description placeholder
      </div>
      <div class="skinSelection">
        <select
          class="skinChoice"
          id="skinChoice"
          name="skinChoice"
          onChange="skinChanged(this.value)"
        >
          <option class="defaultChoice"
            >Choose Your Skin</option
          >
          <option value="water">Water</option>
          <option value="wood">Wood</option>
          <option value="fire">Fire</option>
          <option value="space">Space</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
         const dropDownChoice =
  "document.skinChoice.value";

function setCookie() {
  if (document.cookie != "") {
    dropDownChoice = document.skinChoice.value;
    document.cookie = "dropDownChoice=";
  }
}

function skinChanged(dropDownChoice) {
  if (dropDownChoice == "water") {
    document.body.background =
      "/images/water.jpg";
  } else if (dropDownChoice == "wood") {
    document.body.background = "/images/wood.jpg";
  } else if (dropDownChoice == "fire") {
    document.body.background = "/images/fire.jpg";
  } else if (dropDownChoice == "space") {
    document.body.background =
      "/images/space.jpg";
  }
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: `document.body.style.background = 'url("images/water.jpg")'`, but really, just use a CSS class instead. Also, unless you for some reason have to use cookies, I recommend `localStorage.settings = JSON.stringify(yourObjectOfSettings);`, then `const yourSettingsObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.settings);`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it uses `localStorage` you'll have to run this on your `localhost` instead of here:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, html, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
  return x;
}
post = function(url, send, success, context){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      let s;
      for(let k in send){
        s = send[k];
        if(typeof s === 'object' && s)s = JSON.stringify(s);
        fd.append(k, s);
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments);
  a.shift().classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments);
  a.shift().classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments);
  a.shift().classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
// you can put the following on another page using a load Event - besides the end load
const sets = localStorage.settings ? JSON.parse(localStorage.settings) : {bg:'water'};
const bg_set = I('bg_set');
bg_set.value = sets.bg; aC(bod, sets.bg);
bg_set.onchange = function(){
  rC(bod, 'water', 'wood', 'fire', 'space');
  let v = this.value;
  sets.bg = v; localStorage.settings = JSON.stringify(sets); aC(bod, v);
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#ccc;
}
.main{
  padding:10px;
}
body{
  background-size:cover;
}
body.water{
  background-image:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/734973/pexels-photo-734973.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
}
body.wood{
  background-image:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/172289/pexels-photo-172289.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
}
body.fire{
  background-image:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/57461/fire-burn-hell-warm-57461.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
}
body.space{
  background-image:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1341279/pexels-photo-1341279.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <select id='bg_set'>
      <option value='water'>Water</option>
      <option value='wood'>Wood</option>
      <option value='fire'>Fire</option>
      <option value='space'>Space</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```